# Device excluded by a filter

Tags: debian, lvm, nvme

OS is Debian. Trying to do `pvremove` on a failed nvme, I get the following error:

```
Device /dev/nvme0n1 excluded by a filter.
```

I see no filter set up in lvm.conf.

`pvremove --force` shows the same error. How do I remove this device from lvm pvs?

Output of `pvs`:

```
Error reading device /dev/nvme0n1 at 0 length 4096.
```

I didn't do vgreduce, I don't care about any existing data, I just want this pv gone. Once this pv is gone, I can take a spare nvme, do pvcreate on that, and use it as needed.

The output of vgs and lvs are both currently empty. There **was** a single volume group and some logical volumes that aren't showing up now I'm assuming due to the nvme failure.

I just want lvm to forget about `/dev/nvme0n1` entirely, don't care about data loss here, the nvme is already dead.

Comment: two stupid questions: 1. ) `pvs` does show it, right? can you add the full line of `pvs` to your question 2) you did `vgreduce` the pv from the vg that was using it, right?

Comment: Hey cat pants, I think we'll really need that info to move on!

Comment: Updated! Thank you.

Comment: have you *tried* doing vgreduce first? Otherwise you'd end up with a broken volume group and additional problems. `pvremove` is not *that* useful. It just erases the LVM PV marker at the very beginning of the block device.